# appending data into unselected tab control freezing my game bot for around 1 minute?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Hello stackoverflow..

Currently i'm working on a game bot which connects to game server using Socket and it receives data from the game server.
However Tab_1 got game connection setting ,Tab_2 holds a textbox which is game chat.
When i debug my app and connect to server directly without selecting Tab_2 and the bot receives chat data it append it to textbox which is at Tab_2. 
now the problem , When i select Tab_2 the whole program freeze for about 1 minute and of course my socket disconnected also i can't fine the textbox!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand your situation, but I'd recommend that you run the socket connection to the game server on a different thread than the UI thread. Then you do have the complications of cross-thread communication between the UI thread and the socket thread, but still it will be a better design and less likely to cause problems once you get it working.

Comment: That's what i'm really doing, socket connection got it's own thread even it's received data handles on another class and from that data class i append text into textbox using "static Form1 MainWindow;".

Comment: To send data from your socket thread to your UI thread you need to use control.Invoke() or control.BeginInvoke() to dispatch a method in your Form class.

Comment: hmm can u explain more how can i do that using textbox.appendtext(message)?
Btw i have tried to write a method in UI thread to append texts to textbox and just call this method from Data thread and that's not working too.

Comment: There are several ways of doing this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131453/update-winform-controls-from-another-thread-and-class and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211533/update-a-control-in-ui-with-running-background-thread-in-winforms are the top three Google hits I found.