# How to refresh grid every 10 seconds without freezing the Winform

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, static

I have an application which is using multithreads. I am using threads, becuase applicaiton is used by a user and it runs a database process in background. I dont want application to be frozen while it is doing database process. Everything is fine upto here.

Now, I need to display the processed datas to the user every 10 seconds. I will basically run a SELECT statement to DB and display the result on grid. I tried to run SELECT statement in the thread and display it in grid, but thread is static and Winform/GridControl is not. How can I refresh the gridcontrol's data every 10 seconds without freezing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these other answers. You can safely update the UI thread from background threads using these methods:

[update a control in UI with running background Thread in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211533/update-a-control-in-ui-with-running-background-thread-in-winforms)

[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)