# How to run a Form in a dedicated thread

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm running a command line app, and I want to add an optional form to it that visualizes what's going on in the background. Mostly to see if everything works as intended, as the final product will link to another program with it's own interface.

My question is how to do this without interrupting the main thread.

My current code:

```cs
var stuff = CreateStuff();

Visualization visualization = new Visualization(stuff); //Visualization is my subclass of Windows.Form
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.Run(visualization);

stuff = UpdateStuff(stuff);
```

That last line is not reached as long as the application is open, hence my question.

Specifically, I want to the visualization to continue updating the visuals of what's going on inside `stuff` while the code runs. (If possible even while I step through the code.)

Comment: [Adding MenuItems to Contextmenu for a TrayIcon in a Console app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65048753/7444103) (you can of course replace the NotifyIcon with a Form or have both)

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the visualization code to a separate method, say `void ShowUI()`.
2. Run ShowUI on a background thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(ShowUI);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Note that this UI thread will not be the same thread as your "main thread". You will also need to ensure that [all UI updates run on the UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211533/update-a-control-in-ui-with-running-background-thread-in-winforms).

But it is not clear what you mean by "link to another program". You should ideally make your test UI use the same API as the third party program, whatever that API is.

Comment: I'm developing a pathfinding algorithm for a speedrunning game, but hooking it up to the game requires me to fork a mod and add some things to it's API. For now this is a way to have some visualization of what I'm doing, and later it'll be useful to debug if there happen to be bugs in the algorithm.
Anyways, thanks for the help!